# Directory permission

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod, ls, chown

I am running 12.04 x64 server on ext4 disk. There are two user groups 'A' and 'B'. For a specific directory, I would like to give its all permissions to user group 'A'. Also I would like to give only 'write' permission to user group 'B'. A user of 'B' should only be allowed to write a file or create directory in the directory.

(Should not be allowed to open or read a file.)

I tried with acl as below but not worked well.

`sudo setfacl -d -m g:GROUPB:-wx /mydirectory`

#### Result:

The user of GROUPB could not entered 'mydirectory' because of permission denied error.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`setfacl -m d:g:grpB:-wx /tmp/testgrp/` This works for me.

When grpA:userA creates a file under **/tmp/testgrp/testA** and

When grpB:userB tries to cat the file, it throws a message saying **permission denied**.

But the same user(grpB:UserB) tries to `touch /tmp/testgrp/testB` it creates a file named testB and grpA:UserA can do `cat /tmp/testgrp/testB` to display the file contents

Hope this helps